# React - Child componet stylesheet overwriting other child's stylesheet

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to apply separate `styleSheets` for every child component by importing different `styleSheets` in different components but fails to achieve this as styles are being overwritten.

**Sample Code: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1q4gem?file=Hello.js)**

**childa.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import "./childa.css"

export default () => <h1>Child A!</h1>;
```

**childa.css:**

```
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

**childb.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import "./childb.css"

export default () => <h1>Child B!</h1>;
```

**childb.css:**

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

This is just a sample code. Need solution for a project having large `styleSheets`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification in one of your comments:

> The thing is I'm converting a project from angular to react and all
>   the css is already written so I can't use inline style. Is there any
>   way in which I don't have to rename all the css classes in all the
>   stylesheets?

*Short ans: You can't achieve that as of now.*

This article explains all the different *[ways to style react components](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822)*. In your case, the best that you can do is use **`css modules`** and rename generic classes like `h1` to `.h1`.

Check this great article about css modules: ***[Modular CSS with React](https://medium.com/@pioul/modular-css-with-react-61638ae9ea3e)***.

**Note:** `css modules` are not available in `create-react-app`. If you must use it here's an
article on *[how to use CSS Modules with create-react-app](https://medium.com/nulogy/how-to-use-css-modules-with-create-react-app-9e44bec2b5c2)*.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by ther order of the imports.
In your parent component you have something like

```
import React from 'react'
import ChildA from './ChildA'
import ChildB from './ChildB'
```

This means that in the compiled code you'll have the two stylesheets imported one after the other, and the second `h1` rule will overwrite the first

You should use classes for your components, or use inline style

Comment: The thing is I'm converting a project from angular to react and all the `css` is already written so I can't use inline style. Is there any way in which I don't have to rename all the `css` classes in all the `stylesheets`?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you used generic tag classes (like `h1`) I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Importing a css does not wrap it in the scope of the component is just a straight import into the DOM. In order to mantain a separation of components styles you have to approach with another solution, as styled-components.

Comment: All the css is already written so I can't use styled-components.

Answer (score -1):

This may not work for your entire application, but I fixed it by applying a class to the element (.childA and .childB). This solved the problem.

```
export default () => <h1 className='childB'>Child B!</h1>;
```